# Customized dropdown using jquery and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm looking for customized drop down using **Jquery** with **bootstrap**  .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to style your dropdown options in the form you want it to be:

An example of the same is:

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
  <div class="text">File</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">New</div>
    <div class="item">
       <span class="description">ctrl + o</span>
       Open...
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <span class="description">ctrl + s</span>
       Save as...
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       <span class="description">ctrl + r</span>
       Rename
    </div>
   <div class="item">Make a copy</div>
   <div class="item">
     <i class="folder icon"></i>
     Move to folder
</div>
<div class="item">
  <i class="trash icon"></i>
  Move to trash
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="item">Download As...</div>
<div class="item">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  Publish To Web
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Google Docs</div>
    <div class="item">Google Drive</div>
    <div class="item">Dropbox</div>
    <div class="item">Adobe Creative Cloud</div>
    <div class="item">Private FTP</div>
    <div class="item">Another Service...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">E-mail Collaborators</div>
```

Comment: Any demo for that  dropdown @ashish

Comment: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html  You can refer to various kind of customized dropdowns here

Comment: Yes it is open source and can be installed this way: http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html